# NIC を無効にした状態で Ping すると応答が返ってこない

Tags: c#, windows

動作PCの IP アドレスが 192.168.10.10 であり、その NIC を無効にした状態で以下を実施すると、Send() から応答が返ってきません。 NIC を有効にすると指定したタイムアウト値で応答が返ります。
この動作は正しい挙動でしょうか？
正しい場合、どうやってSend()から制御を戻せばいいでしょうか？
ping 先の "172.17.10.20" には何も接続していない状態です。

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

Ping sender = new Ping();
sender.Send("172.17.10.20", 1*1000); // この関数からnic無効にすると応答が返ってこない
```

**環境：**

- Windows10 64bit
- Visual Studio 2017
- C#

以上、宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 古い記事ですが、こんなのがあります。[VB.NETでpingをとばす際に気を付けなければならないこと](http://micronwave.hatenablog.jp/entry/20140621/1403328801), [Pingを送信する: .NET Tips: C#, VB.NET](http://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/internet/ping.html)

Comment: いつも情報ありがとうございます。同じサイトみてPingクラスに問題があるのか、と思っていたのですが、対処方法わかりました。
.net 4.5.x と .net 4.6.x で動作が違っていて全く気が付かなかったのですが、.net 4.6.x ではSend()発行時に例外が発行されておりました。なぜか .net 4.5.x では例外が発行されず、Send() の戻りか返ってこないように見えていました（デバッカー上では）。ところが、.net 4.6.x と同じように例外キャッチ(try,catch)すると、ネットワーク異常が正しく検出することができました。windows7等でも動作確認が必要なのでもう少ししらべて結果を記載して終了とします。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 記事はlocalhostというか、ループバックアドレス（127.0.0.1)について記載されているようです。対してソースは172.17.10.20、これだとnicを通して外側に投げているように見えますが、なぜnicを無効にしても返ってくると考えられているのでしょうか？たとえば同一ホスト内にvirtualな環境があって、Virtual NICを形成されているからとかそういうお話でしょうか？もしくは、自分の端末のIPが172.17.10.20だからでしょうか。。疑問に思ったので後学のために教えてください。

Comment: 本件、windows7(32bit),windows10(64bit)で、.net45x, .net46x 共に、Send()時に例外をキャッチすることで期待通りの動作となることを確認しました。

Comment: コメント見逃してました。ループバック云々とか全く気にしておらず、単純に関数応答（タイムアウト）があると思い込んでいただけです。

Comment: もし解決した場合には、コメント欄ではなく個別の回答として投稿してみてください。

Answer (score -2):

NIC…Network Interface Card　あるいは Network Interface Controller　の略
IPネットワーク処理そのものを管理したり自分のIPそのものと対応するパーツ/機能ですので、
そのマシンのネットワーク機能の根幹に支障が出るのではないでしょうか。